Profile and header image for the cogsci.SE facebook page
Please suggest a profile and header image for the cogsci.SE Facebook page.
Either describe your idea, or post the (or an example) image.
Make sure you have the right to that image, that it is in the public domain, licensed under Creative Commons for non-commercial use, free stock, or something similar. Always post a link to the source so we can check the license.
Related: Let's create a Facebook page for cogsci.SE

This is what our Facebook page currently looks like:


Here are some examples made after Nick's suggestion. All images are released under Creative Commons.
The sculpture "Soma" was made by Flamin Lotus Girls and exhibited at Burning Man 2009.
The logo ("CS") is just an example and not (necessarily) the final version.
Please vote for the image you prefer by giving the number(s) in a comment, or let me know what you would change.
1

2

3

4 a

4 b

4 c

4

5

6

7

8


Facebook Timeline Dimensions:


The other pictures you found are great! I rank them 3 > 4 > 2 > 1 > 8 > 6 > 5 > 7, but I'd like 4 best if you could show a little more of the top part of the cover photo, and a little less of the bottom part. I like the lens flare on the dendritic terminals, but don't mind seeing a little bit of the people crowded around if it costs the very top terminal – kind of nice just to make it clear that it's a great big sculpture. In general, I prefer the simpler font over the cursive script version of the logo.

Which variant of 4 do you prefer now?

Ooh...tough one...Toss-up between 4a & 4c! Nice work all around BTW!

Then I vote for 4a, because when you visit a FB page, at first you only see the bottom half of the header image and have to scroll up to see it all.

I prefer something that emphasizes the scientific aspect of our work. My idea for the cover photo was a picture of a neuron. This might seem a little odd coming from a social / personality psychologist! This particular image is a little less emphatic of the biological reality though, and highlights the representation of neural structure through the human mind and artificial modeling, which seem appropriate to me.

I haven't tried cropping it, but I imagine it'll work out all right.
Here's the source. The image has a Creative Commons Attribution-NonCommercial-NoDerivs 2.0 Generic license.
My idea for the profile picture is a popular drawing from Descartes' Meditations Métaphysiques:

This image is in the public domain. It should be quite recognizable within our field, and is suitable for a profile picture in that it depicts a person in profile. Wikipedia's caption for this picture may suggest a problem, however: "Inputs are passed by the sensory organs to the pineal gland and from there to the immaterial spirit." This idea is over three centuries old, so it might represent the historical nature of cognitive science well enough, but whether that's an aspect of the field to which we want to appeal is a question worth considering IMHO...especially given the current status of dualistic theory and our concerns about distinguishing our theories from pseudoscience.

I like the neuron and am all for it. I think the drawing from Descartes will not took so good when it is resized as a small profile picture, for example alongside comments. I'd prefer something more simple and visually clear that resizes well, as a profile picture.

I made some samples. What do you think?

It occurs to me now that Descartes' drawing could be cropped rather than shrunk. Even the head by itself would probably be recognizable if that's all that shows up in the thumbnail. I'm not especially attached to the idea though.
